# .net 6.0 Deployment on Windows server for api

Tags: .net, iis

i am looking for some help on a .net 6 api project deployment, which i am not able to deploy.

I have it running on one server windows 2019 Server, but when i put it on another server(same config) it's failing.
I have tried to keep all server settings the same. i keep getting 500 error.

i have the project deployed on 2 servers

Not sure if this is relevant but

the .net section is not showing up in the server where it's not working, i have reinstalled the full OS and IIS to make sure the windows was not corrupt

[image]

https://api.atmtoken.io/api/test (fails)

https://testapi.atmtoken.io/api/test (works - same code on another server)

if i click on http response icon on server 2 in iis it's not working, geting an error
there was an error while performing this operation details : filename \?\c:\intetpub\apitoken2\web.config Error

Comment: Alright, 500 error may occur when the web.config contains modules that are not installed. Although you have reinstalled IIS, please check that you have actually installed the asp.net module. Refer to official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45. Restart after installation for testing. If you have further questions, you will need to provide screenshots of IIS installation module in Server Manager and web.config configuration.